# How to show certain files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wish to hide .js file & .map file extensions, but to display some .js files that are important to my project. 
When I use the following to hide:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {

        "**/*.js": true,
        "**/*.js.map": true
    } 

}
```

Everything gets hidden. How can I display specific files while the rest are hidden?

Comment: I think the only way you can achieve this is by putting the files you want to see in a different folder, then change your files.exclude statement accordingly. I.e., show the folder with your files and hide js and js.map in all other folders.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to hide `.js` files only when there is a `.ts` file with the same name, so you need to add condition:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": {
            "when": "$(basename).ts"
        },
        "**/*.js.map": true
    } 

}
```